# How to release memory used by MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I am using MediaElement to show video clips in a loop for long period of time. After some time (hours for Win 7 / 4 GB RAM) the program crashes with exception of type "Insufficient memory". I have monitored the memory used while playing with Process Explorer-Sysinternals and also logged it using System.Diagnostics.Process methods. Both ways show gradually increasing of used memory.

Here is the code:

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="GridTest">
    <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                  LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                  MediaEnded="VideoControl_MediaEnded"
                  MediaOpened="MediaPlayer_MediaOpened"
                  Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay,
                                   Path=MySource}" />
</Grid>
```

.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.GridTest.DataContext = model;

        // fill in model.MediaFilesUris:
        ...
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // choose the next media file 
        ...

        MediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    private void VideoControl_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // choose the next media file 
        ...

        model.OnPropertyChanged("MySource");

        MediaPlayer.Play();
    }
}


public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    { 
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
    }

    public Uri[] MediaFilesUris = null;
    public int crn = 0;

    public Uri MySource { get { if (MediaFilesUris != null && MediaFilesUris.Count()>0) return MediaFilesUris[crn]; else return null; } }

}
```

I have also tested the case when MediaElement object is created dynamically, destroyed (together with all unsubscribing from events, etc.) after several clips and created again. Memory got consumed increasingly again.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you "destroying" your MediaElement? This is a UI element and WPF does a terrible job GC'ing UI elements.

Comment: Tried to make Source = null in the end of playing? You defintely shoud try.

Comment: Here is how I "destroy" the MediaElement obejct (created programmatically, not in XAML):                                  MediaPlayer.Stop();
MediaPlayer.MediaEnded -= MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
MediaPlayer.MediaOpened -= MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;
MediaPlayer.Close();
GridTest.Children.Remove(MediaPlayer);
MediaPlayer = null;
GC.Collect();
If created with binding the Source property, also before Close(): BindingOperations.ClearBinding(MediaPlayer, MediaElement.SourceProperty);

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify MediaElement `UnloadingBehavior="Close"`property in your XAML.

According to MSDN `MediaState::Close` indicates that

> All media resources are released (including video memory).

Comment: Thank you, I will test it in next cases. This one was solved by using Generic Windows video driver

Comment: The property name is `MediaElement.UnloadedBehavior` to be pedantic - 
[Docs - MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.unloadedbehavior?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-controls-mediaelement-unloadedbehavior)

Comment: doesnt work. or do i have to do sth specific?

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to make the following:

```
private void VideoControl_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // choose the next media file 
    ...
    //make the following explicitly
    MediaPlayer.Stop();      
    MediaPlayer.Source = null;

    model.OnPropertyChanged("MySource");

    MediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

Comment: Tried also MediaPlayer.Stop(); MediaPlayer.Source = null; MediaPlayer.Close(); and then reassigned Source in VideoControl_MediaEnded() with no effect.

Comment: @MDimitrov Hmmm, you can also try to assign null to the entire MediaPlayer object and then reinstantiate it.

Comment: I thried this also, wrote about it in a comment above where described how I "destroyed" the object

Comment: @MDimitrov Have you tried to use a tool such as DotMemory by JetBrains in order to analyze your memory traffic? I feel like your case is not so simple as I thought at the first sight.

Comment: I have used VMMap - Sysinternals which shows no released memory after I "destroy" the MediaElement object. After creating it again the memory use continues to grow, e.g. Private Bytes but I will dig into it deeper, will try DotMemory too.

Comment: Seems that the problem is caused by an incompatible video driver. The program works well with the generic Windows driver.

Comment: @MDimitrov Yes, after you said that assigning null does not help it became obvious that there is something strange is going on.